# ASP MVC 3 - Export to CSV method including junk characters not in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, csv, export-to-csv

Below is the (crude) method I'm using to export the contents of a table into a CSV. I came up with this on the fly, however the data in the table has been loaded from an Excel spreadsheet created by a Sharepoint site. I do not know if that conversion process or my method is the cause, but a large number of these characters: `Â` are being imported into the cells.

Also, a large number of records are having their fields split up into two rows as opposed to just one. This is my first attempt at exporting to a CSV programatically (as opposed to using excel) so any help would be greatly apprecitated.

Controller Method

```
    public ActionResult ExportToCsv()
    {
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var banks = db.BankListMaster.Include(b => b.BankListAgentId).ToList();

            writer.WriteLine("Bank Name, EPURL, AssociatedTPMBD, Tier, FixedLifeMasterSAF, VariableLifeMasterSAF, FixedLifeSNY, VariableLifeMasterSNY, SpecialNotes, WelcomeLetterReq, " +
                             "BackOfficeNotification, LinkRepsToDynamics, RelationshipCode, INDSGC, PENSGC, LicensingContract, MiscellaneousNotes, ContentTypeID1, CreatedBy, MANonresBizNY, Attachment");

            foreach (var item in banks)
            {
                writer.Write(item.BankName + ",");
                if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.EPURL))
                {
                    writer.Write(item.EPURL + ",");
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Write(item.EPURL.Trim() + ",");
                }
                writer.Write(item.AssociatedTPMBD + ",");
                writer.Write(item.Tier + ",");
                writer.Write(item.LicensingContract + ",");
                writer.Write(item.MiscellaneousNotes + ",");
                writer.Write(item.ContentTypeID1 + ",");
                writer.Write(item.CreatedBy + ",");
                writer.Write(item.MANonresBizNY + ",");
                writer.Write(item.Attachment);
                writer.Write(writer.NewLine);
            }

            return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(writer.ToString().Replace("Â", "")), "text/csv", "BankList.csv");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as the two rows, I suspect your Miscellaneous Notes field might contain carriage return/line feeds in it.   Try item.Miscellaneous.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is a file format that's poorly specified. Several important things aren't specified:

- The field separator. Even though it's called "comma separated", Excel will use the semicolon sometimes (depending on your locale!).
- The encoding (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ANSI/Windows-1252 etc.)
- The kind of newlines (CR, NL or CR NL).
- Whether all fields have to be quoted with double quotes or just the ones containing the field separator, the line separator, blanks etc.
- Whether white space is trimmed from unquoted fields.
- Whether newlines are allowed within quoted fields (Excel allows them).
- How double quotes are escaped if they are part of the field content (normally they are doubled)

Excel is usually the reference for a valid CSV format. But even Excel chooses the field separator and the encoding depending on your locale.

In your case, the encoding is most likely the main problem. You use UTF-8 but the consumer treats it as ISO-8859-1 or ANSI. For that reason, the character `Â` often appears whose binary code is used in UTF-8 to introduce a two byte sequence. Change the encoding to fix the `Â`.

As the next step, properly quote the text fields, i.e. add double quotes at the start and at the end and double all double quotes within the field.